# Count bits in character and tally the bits

Tags: c, bit

This is only my 2nd programming class. There are 30 rooms, we have to see what is in each room and tally it. I already used the for loop to go through the 30 rooms and I know I have to use a bit counter to see what is in each room. I don't know how to count the bits in a word. Below are sample inputs/outputs and what I have so far in code.

Sample input:

```
9   23  @Z
```

If the key is:

```
0 gold_bar
1 silver_bar
2 diamond
3 copper_ring
4 jumpy_troll
5 air
6 angry_troll
7 plutonium_troll
```

And the line is 9 23 @Z then room at 9,23 (character Z with binary: 01011010) has items 1, 3, 4, 6. silver_bar, copper_ring, jumpy_troll, angry_troll

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
// contains x and y coordinate
 int first, second;
  char third[100];
char Map[30][30];

// map initialization
for(int x=0; x<30; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<30; y++){
        Map[x][y] = '.';
    }
}


while(scanf("%d %d %s",&first, &second, third) != -1) {
    // Condition 1: a zero coordinate
    if (first==0 || second==0) exit(0);
    // Condition 2: coordinate out of range
    if (first<0 || first>30 || second<0 || second>30){
        printf("Error: out of range 0-30!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
// bit counter
    for( int bit_p=0; bit_p<8; bit_p++){

    }

    Map[second-1][first-1] = third[1];


return 0;
}
```

Sample input:

```
1   20  @@
2   21  @A
3   22  @#
4   23  @1
5   22  @@
6   22  @@
7   22  @@
8   22  @@
9   23  @Z  Here be trolls � not!
10  23  @+
12  23  @@
13  24  @@
11  22  @@
14  22  @2
15  21  @1
16  20  @@
17  19  @@
18  20  @@
19  19  @@
20  18  @@
21  17  @*
22  16  @*
23  15  @%
0   14  @7
0   gold_bar
1   silver_bar
2   diamond
3   copper_ring
4   jumpy_troll
5   air
6   angry_troll
7   plutonium_troll
```

Sample Output:

```
6   gold_bar
6   silver_bar
1   diamond
4   copper_ring
4   jumpy_troll
8   air
15  angry_troll
0   plutonium_troll
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Comment: @Olaf I think the title of the question is misleading...

Comment: @Matthieu: If it is really just about counting if a specific bit is set, OP really should have done research on her own.

Comment: I guess we do not have the same definition of counting...

Answer (score 4):

The individual bits of a word are not directly accessible with C, so we have to do other things to get at them.

Consider your values, which give which bit is set:

```
0 gold_bar          00000001B  or 0x01
1 silver_bar        00000010B  or 0x02
2 diamond           00000100B  or 0x04
3 copper_ring       00001000B  or 0x08
4 jumpy_troll       00010000B  or 0x10
5 air               00100000B  or 0x20
6 angry_troll       01000000B  or 0x40
7 plutonium_troll   10000000B  or 0x80
```

So with observation, lets consider what will happen if we have the following:

```
unsigned char test = 'z'
unsigned char res = test & 0x02
```

Now as you stated 'z' has a binary representation of 01111010 and if we do a logical and with 2 we have:

```
     z: 01111010B
  0x02: 00000010B
        ----------
        00000010B
```

So the expression test & 0x02 evaluates to 0x02.  So, how can we use this?  We can write something like:

```
     if((test & 0x02) == 0x02)
         ++cntSilverBars;
```

Extending this we have, assuming we have appropriately defined variables (*i.e* cntAuBars would be declared as int cntAuBars and hold the number of gold bars discovered:

```
     if((test & 0x01) == 0x01)
         ++cntAuBars;
     if((test & 0x02) == 0x02)
         ++cntAgBars;
     if((test & 0x04) == 0x04)
         ++cntDiamonds;
     if((test & 0x08) == 0x08)
         ++cntCuRings;
     if((test & 0x10) == 0x10)
         ++cntJumpyTroll;
     if((test & 0x20) == 0x20)
         ++cntSilverBars;
     if((test & 0x40) == 0x40)
         ++cntAir;
     if((test & 0x80) == 0x80)
         ++cntPuTroll;
```

While the above will work, it can be re-written as:

```
int itemCnt[8] = {0};         // array to hold count of items, index is item type
unsigned char test;           // holds contents of room.
int loc;
for(loc = 0; loc < 8; loc++)  // loop over every bit and see if it is set
{
     unsigned char bitPos = 1 << loc;  // generate a bit-mask 
     if((test & bitPos) == bitPos)
          ++itemCnt[loc];
}
```

For example, the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  unsigned char test = 'z';
  int           items[8] = {0};
  int           loc;
  int           ndx;

  for(loc = 0; loc < 8; loc++)
  {
      unsigned bitPos = 1 << loc;
      if((test & bitPos) ==  bitPos)
          ++items[loc];
  }


  for(ndx = 0; ndx < 8; ndx++)
  {
     printf("%d, ", items[ndx]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

can be compiled as: `gcc -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall temp.c -o temp`, and when run produces the following array (when view in a debugger):

```
(gdb) print /t 'z'
$7 = 1111010
(gdb) print items
$8 = {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}
```

Comment: thanks! how do i output the data so it's 6   gold_bar
6   silver_bar
1   diamond
4   copper_ring
4   jumpy_troll
8   air
15  angry_troll
0   plutonium_troll? 
Do I need to declare the variables?

Comment: @janny the array keeps track of things.  The number of gold bars will be contained in the first element of the array (*i.e.* items[0]) just make sure the item array is declared outside of the loops that iterate over the rooms

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong, I wrote printf("%d", itemCnt[0]); and the output is just 00000000000000000000000

Comment: @janny added code to show how to print out the array.  Also noticed I had a mistake in the loop (which I fix)

Answer (score 1):

This code examines a character and fills an array of 8 ints with value 0 if the bit at that position is 0 and value 1 if the bit at that position is 1

```
char c = 'Z';
int bits[8];
int n;
char aux = c;
for ( n=0; n<8; ++n ) {
  if ( aux & '\1' )
    bits[n] = 1;
  else
    bits[n] = 0;
  aux = aux >> 1;
}
```

`aux & '\1'` and `aux = aux >> 1` are the heard of the code.

'\1' is the character with ASCII code 1 thus its bit at position 0 is 1 and all other bits are 0. When we do a bitwise AND of '\1' with a character we get 1 if that character a 1 at bit position 0 and we get a 0 otherwise.

`aux = aux >> 1` will shift bits one position to the left so that in the next operation the bit at postion 0 will be the one which was originally at position 1.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in function for accumulating bit counts in a word.  For each room, you'll need to check each of the 8 bits and, if that bit is set, increment the appropriate counting variable.  There are many ways to do this, but especially for a class you want to do it as clearly as possible.

The basic idea is that you want to compare the word you read in ("third", in your framework) to a single bit mask shifted up to the bit position you're testing.  Do the comparison by and'ing the mask against the input in and testing it using if statement.  I've dropped a sample into your framework:

```
// bit counter
for( int bit_p=0; bit_p<8; bit_p++){
    if (third & (1 << bit_p))
        tally[bit_p]++;
}
```

The common piece is the structure `if (input & MASK) {do_whatever}`.  Once you understand why that structure works, you can apply it to many situations.